# Why the operator is termed as Ornstein–Uhlenbeck operator?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soft-question, stochastic-processes, terminology

The Ornstein–Uhlenbeck operator is clearly stated in the link below. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_operator In the link it is also stated that "not to be confused with Ornstein–Uhlenbeck Process"

The question is why the the operator is named after them? Why it is called by the name "Ornstein–Uhlenbeck operator"? Is there a connection between the process and the operator, could not find one. Any suggestion?

Comment: I doubt there is any connection beyond "these two people both worked on both of these things".

Comment: @Ian could not find any literature on their name  when looked for extension of Laplace operator to infinite dimensional case.

Comment: @Ian: Au contraire; see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are closely connected.  The operator is the [infinitesimal generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_generator_(stochastic_processes)) of the process.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was expecting something like this but never could have found out on my own.