# Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Operator as an Infinitesimal Generator of a Stochastic Process

Tags: stochastic-processes

This question continues the discussion from an earlier post on this website found here :
[Why the operator is termed as Ornstein–Uhlenbeck operator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2646843/why-the-operator-is-termed-as-ornstein-uhlenbeck-operator)  I am interested in the relationship between the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck operator
$L f(x)=\Delta f(x) - x\cdot\nabla f(x)$  and the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck stochastic process. The earlier post states that the operator is the infinitesimal generator of the [stochastic] process. When I select the provided link which routes the reader to a Wikipedia post, the infinitesimal generator for the Ornstein- Uhlenbeck process on $\mathbb{R}$ which this post lists is this one :
$$ \mathcal{A}f(x)=\theta(\mu-x)f'(x)+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}f''(x)\ .$$
Specifically, my questions are the following.

(1) How can the generator $\mathcal{A}f(x)$ be written in the form given by $L f(x)$ ? If possible, I am interested in seeing the steps by which $\mathcal{A}f(x)$ can be rewritten as the form $L f(x)$.

(2) How did Ornstein and Uhlenbeck use the operator $L f(x) $ in their research ?  If possible, I am intersted in any source references.

Comment: Consider the operator $L$ in one dimension (which is the case $A$ is written in) so that e.g. $\Delta f = f''$. Now notice that you got the formula for $A$ with $\sigma^2 =2, \mu=0, \theta =1$.